# ESP8266 doesn't boot properly if GPIO pin connected

Tags: arduino, relay, wifi, esp8266

I'm using an ESP8266 board to control a relay via a transistor like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftXcrv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, when I boot the ESP8266 with the GPIO0 pin connected as shown, the blue LED is on constantly, as if in a constant reset or a flash mode. If I connect the GPIO once the boot has finished, it works fine. Does anyone know a way around this issue?

I am using the Arduino IDE to program the board with this code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "PWORD";

int ledPin = 2; // GPIO2 of ESP8266
WiFiServer server(80);//Service Port

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  // Print the IP address
  Serial.print("Use this URL to connect: ");
  Serial.print("http://");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println("/");
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }

  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }

  // Read the first line of the request
  String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(request);
  client.flush();

  // Match the request

  int value = LOW;
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=ON") != -1) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    value = HIGH;
  } 
  if (request.indexOf("/LED=OFF") != -1){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    value = LOW;
  }

  //Set ledPin according to the request
  //digitalWrite(ledPin, value);

  // Return the response
  client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
  client.println(""); //  do not forget this one
  client.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML>");
  client.println("<html>");

  client.print("Led pin is now: ");

  if(value == HIGH) {
    client.print("On");  
  } else {
    client.print("Off");
  }
  client.println("<br><br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=ON\">here</a> turn the LED on pin 2 ON<br>");
  client.println("Click <a href=\"/LED=OFF\">here turn the LED on pin 2 OFF<br>");
  client.println("</html>");

  delay(1);
  Serial.println("Client disconnected");
  Serial.println("");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Several GPIO states are required on boot, including that GPIO0 be high. This has been covered several times before, expect the question to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: use GPIO 1 or 2 instead.

Answer (score 2):

Read [this](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=esp8266_gpio_pin_allocations).

Your 3k resistor is enough to pull GPIO0 low during powerup and the ESP8266 is likely going into serial load mode.

Use a FET to drive your relay if you want to use GPIO0 .....and put a diode across the coil.

Comment: This means the relay will be on at boot - which may or may not be acceptable.

Comment: Correct. If that does not suit the OP then he could use a P-Chan FET.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i see is you turn ON the built in led on setup()

pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    <--- This turns LED on.

Also, not shown in diagram, but you should pull GPIO0 high, with a pull-up resistor, possibly 20 kOhm. I would not choose something smaller as it would turn on the transistor on boot up (unless that's not a problem for you).

Hope this helps!

Comment: 20K won't accomplish anything.  Because the transistor base sinks current, the pullup resistor will have to be on the same order as the base resistor (preferably less than a third of its value), or it won't make the pin actually high as needed.  This will indeed mean turning on the relay during boot.

Comment: This is very late, but why does writing LOW to the ledPin turn the LED on? I was having a similar problem and this was the exact fix, but should writing HIGH turn it on?

Comment: @user342354 I guess thats because the Pin is Active LOW